# Black screen makes Grub and BIOS inaccessible after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer recently, with the idea of having a dual boot with Windows 10. I used the traditional method of the USB drive, but I ran into some issues and I ended up adding `acpi=off` after `quiet splash` and installing it in UEFI mode and secure mode off (not completely sure about this last point, I tried different things).

The problem is that now my laptop boots with a black screen until it enters Ubuntu, making the bios and Grub inaccessible. I have the feeling that Grub is been executed because if I press enter it boots faster, and it is just a matter of what is appearing on the screen.

I have tried to add `nomodset` but it didn't improve anything. Any idea of what can be going on?

Comment: To regain access to your grub menu, follow the steps as given: 

1) Press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` on your keyboard to open terminal.  2) When it opens, run the command(s) below:

`update-grub` 

3) If this fails,  then try

`apt-get install --reinstall grub`

then

`grub-install`

and finally at end

`update-grub`

this should help you.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. My guess is that it is a problem related to the video drivers, but it is difficult to say. I have a Dell Inspiron 7559 btw.

Comment: Post researching on Google, I came across this link - `http://xahlee.info/comp/dell_inspiron_15_7559_linux_boot_problem.html` 

See if it helps you in any way. If not we will look for other options.

Comment: Follow up: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010514/black-screen-when-loading-ubuntu`