# Black screen when loading Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

A few days ago I posted about [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008630/black-screen-makes-grub-and-bios-inaccessible-after-installing-ubuntu), which not only I didn't solve, but I  made things worse trying to solve it.

The new problem was caused by updating the kernel, as I see that someone suggested somewhere else. The installation went smoothly, besides some warnings that my integrated GPU may have some drivers missing (I think this is the main problem here). However, now Ubuntu loads, but I can't see anything on the screen. I have also tried to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but nothing happened.

So summing up:

- I cannot access the bios or see grub, making it difficult to repair the Ubuntu partition with a bootable USB.
- I cannot do anything in Ubuntu: based on the sounds it loads, but I cannot see anything on the screen
- I still have access to the windows partition.

Additional information: Dell Inspiron 7559, Nvidia drivers 387. And my grub file in etc/default looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset i915_bpo.modeset=1 quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=native acpi_osi="
```

Comment: Can you boot into the recovery mode ?

Comment: I have been trying to do so by taking a look at the grub menu at `boot/grub/grub.cfg` and then moving the selection based on that, but no luck so far (I don't know if it is because I am making a mistake with the selections or because it is just not working).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up tearing apart my computer and disconnecting the CMOS battery for a few minutes. That resets the BIOS.